# IIS 7.0 configuration issue in Windows Server 2008

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have configured the IIS / our web application in two Windows 2008 Server. One is working fine and the other one is facing User Rights / Security Issue.

Error Message from Server # 2 :

HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error

The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.

When i compared with Server # 1, i am missing the ASP.Net in the Server # 2.

I wonder that might cause the issue.

[image]

Comment: Is ASP.Net installed on Server #2? Are the permissions set up to allow the requests to use IIS, sometimes the ASP.Net extensions aren't allowed by default?

Comment: How do i make sure ASP.Net Installed. Well,I have installed .Net framework from 1.0 - 4.0

Comment: You could use the `aspnet_regiis` utility as described in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h.aspx for one idea.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find  the solution for the IIS Configuration Issue.

Go to Control Panel\Programs and Features

Click : Turn Windows Features On or Off

Under Server Manager : - Click Roles

Add Role Servers, Select Role Services - Check Application Development (ASP.Net) and continue the Installation.

This solved my purpose.